# Beamer: font style applied to all blocks in bibliography?

Tags: beamer, fonts, bibliographies

I'm writing a poster with `beamer` and `beamerposter`. I add some styles to the bibliography with the dedicated commands. Below is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}

\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}

\setbeamerfont{bibliography item}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{size=\footnotesize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{size=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{thebibliography}{99}

            \bibitem{Hecht12}
                Frédéric \textsc{Hecht},
                \newblock{New Development in FreeFem++,}
                \newblock{Journal of Numerical Mathematics,}
                \newblock{vol. 20, no. 3--4, pp. 251--265, 2012.}

            \bibitem{Nedelec86}
                Jean-Claude \textsc{Nédélec},
                \newblock{A New Family of Mixed Finite Elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$,}
                \newblock{Numerische Mathematik,}
                \newblock{vol. 50, no. 1, pp. 57--81, 1986.}

            \bibitem{Monk03}
                Peter \textsc{Monk},
                \newblock{Finite Element Methods for Maxwell's Equations,}
                \newblock{Oxford University Press,}
                \newblock{2003.}

        \end{thebibliography}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem I have is that the size font properties are applied to all blocks, without any limit. If I indicate `\footnotesize` to the title only, the blocks following the first title will also be in this size. The font series is also affected, as you can see in the following screenshot of the result.

[image: Wrong bibliography style]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question, i.e. a full document that can be compiled without further adaption (adding `\documentclass{beamer}` etc.).

Comment: Hi, I just edited the question with the minimal example. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, see the [documentation of the `beamer`-font `bibliography entry author`:](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.10.6)

> [...] Note that the effect of this template will persist until the end of the bibliography item or until one of the following templates undo the effect.

So the easiest solution probably is to fully specify your font templates by including settings like `series=\mdseries` for non-bold text etc.

As an alternative, changing the default `beamer` behaviour to reset the font template for each block would involve patching an internal `beamer` command to use `\usebeamerfont*` instead of the unstarred version `\usebeamerfont`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}

\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}

\setbeamerfont{bibliography item}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{size=\footnotesize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{size=\footnotesize}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\beamer@newblock}{\usebeamerfont}{\usebeamerfont*}{}{}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{thebibliography}{99}

            \bibitem{Hecht12}
                Frédéric \textsc{Hecht},
                \newblock New Development in FreeFem++,
                \newblock Journal of Numerical Mathematics,
                \newblock vol. 20, no. 3--4, pp. 251--265, 2012.

            \bibitem{Nedelec86}
                Jean-Claude \textsc{Nédélec},
                \newblock A New Family of Mixed Finite Elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$,
                \newblock Numerische Mathematik,
                \newblock vol. 50, no. 1, pp. 57--81, 1986.

            \bibitem{Monk03}
                Peter \textsc{Monk},
                \newblock Finite Element Methods for Maxwell's Equations,
                \newblock Oxford University Press,
                \newblock 2003.

        \end{thebibliography}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: compiled bibliography]

(Note that as `\newblock` is supposed to be used as a separator, it doesn't take an argument, so the braces in your example are a bit misleading - that's why I removed them in my code.)